# Bones Wordpress Framework

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, themes, less

I've installed Bones locally, renamed the directory etc, installed WinLess, but there are no less files in the theme library. Can't figure it out, the theme is working perfectly, but I can't find the less files to edit. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.3 removed LESS, and version 1.4 put LESS back in.  I don't see anything in the change log located [here](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) that would say its been removed again, but it appears the current version, which is 1.7, does not have the LESS files in the theme.

You can get the LESS code here: https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/commit/2593f647aea6bc84c1bcc52d12f2a54087e26dce and add them back in yourself, or switch to SCSS or even use basic CSS.